# Multiplying in excel through vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba programming, i want to create a programme that "how to copy n number of columns and rows from one excel sheet to another and multiply all the values from a given constant number"

Comment: Yep. Go ahead and create it then? I don't think anyone here is interested in what you're going to create?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and what research you have done on your problem. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Public Sub Derived_Years()
Dim n As Integer, rng As Range
n = Range("c51").Value - 2
Sheets("Derived Series").Select
Set rng = Range("c6")
rng.Select
line2:
Range(rng.Offset(1, 1), rng.Offset(1, n)).EntireColumn.Insert
Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Copy
Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, n)).PasteSpecial
Set rng = rng.Offset(0, n + 1)
If rng = "" Then
GoTo line1
Else
GoTo line2
End If
line1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("c6").Select
End Sub

Comment: but there is a problem i am not able to multiply a number in this

Comment: Would you kindly edit this into your original question? It's hard to read this way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, as a model:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, C As Double
    C = 0.123
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B9")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B9")

    r1.Copy r2

    For Each r In r2
        r.Value = C * r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```